# Club sets and diagonal intersection

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Let $\kappa$ be **any** regular cardinal, and let $<C_i\mid i<\kappa>$ be a sequence of club sets. Define their diagonal intersection $\Delta C_i$ as follows:

$\Delta C_i = \{\alpha<\kappa \mid \forall i<\alpha:\alpha\in C_i\}$

I must prove that this set is also club. Now, I would like to consider the following supposed counterexample. Clearly, $\omega$ is regular, so if I define the following sequence of sets:

$C_i =\{p_i ^n \mid n\in\mathbb N\}$

Where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime number, we have a sequence of infinite (trivially) club sets with no pairwise intersection. If I understand correctly, this means that every number larger than $1$ is an element of $0$ or $1$ sets, and is not an element of the diagonal intersection. In particular, the diagonal intersection contains only $2$ elements, and so it is not unbounded and not club.

I assume this counterexample fails somewhere, as I was supposed to prove the claim. Can anyone please help me locate my error?

Comment: I looked at a few set theory books on my shelves (because I mainly know about the situation for $\kappa = {\omega}_1$ and wasn't sure of the exact hypothesis used for other cardinals), and the assumption for this diagonal intersection result is that $\kappa$ is a regular cardinal with **uncountable cofinality**. Perhaps you overlooked this aspect, or maybe what you're looking at overlooked saying this (or made this assumption earlier in the discussion and you didn't notice)?

Comment: Ok, so there really was some confusion. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: This result (when $\kappa=cf (\kappa)\geq \omega_1$) is used in proving an important tool known as Fodor's Lemma, or the Pressing-Down Lemma.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When talking about clubs/stationary sets/etc., we have to restrict to *uncountable* regular cardinals - or at least, ordinals of *uncountable cofinality* - to get a nontrivial theory. For example, both $\{$evens$\}$ and $\{$odds$\}$ are club in $\omega$, but their intersection is empty; so it's not even *diagonal* intersection that fails, but *regular* (hehe) intersection!